# How to use a semaphore in python?

Tags: python, semaphore

For accessing a database and to avoid two commits at the same time I am trying to use a `BoundedSemaphore` ([see here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects)) as follows:

```
from threading import BoundedSemaphore
...
commit_sema = BoundedSemaphore(value=1) 

class Sqlite(object):
    ...
    def commit():
        commit_sema.acquire()
        self.conn.commit()  # self.conn is the Connection object
        commit_sema.release()
```

But although I made sure the same instance of the `Sqlite` class is used I saw that a second `commit()` call has been made before the first one has finished.

I had the impression that the second call should be blocked until the first call calls `release()` to increase the `Semaphore` counter. But this is not the case.

So what do I see wrong here? How to do it correctly?

Comment: The `sqlite3` library handles threading just fine, provided you use one connection per thread. There is no need to use any special thread coordination.

Comment: But I get an error `disk I/O error` which just seems to happen when I use `conn.commit()` at the same time. So my best guess was that two commit's are tried at the same time...

Comment: Are you *100% sure* that that is SQLite? Because it knows how to handle concurrent commits just fine.

Comment: sqlite3, python 3.4.3

Comment: No, the disk I/O error. What is the full traceback of that error?

Comment: The error is definitely caused by `self.conn.commit()`. I am 100% sure of it (because I am catching any `sqlite3.Error` during the call to `self.conn.commit()` which causes a specific error message to appear.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alexander/MyProject/Server/play/db_class.py", line 272, in commit
    self.conn.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117745/discussion-between-alex-and-martijn-pieters).